# What is a good lightweight database that can be used for an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, activerecord

I need lightweight database for an ASP.NET MVC application.

- would prefer not to install anything additional on the host box
- would also prefer being a little more robust than XML
- would like to use activerecord or entity frameworks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) claims to have an "XCopy" installation (copy and run), and it would have the fewest integration headaches.

Answer (score 4):

You can check [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 1):

- Sqlite http://www.sqlite.org/
- visadb http://www.vistadb.net/

Answer (score 1):

[Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) can do the job well

> The embedded version is an amazing
>   variation of the server. It is a fully
>   featured Firebird server packed in
>   just a few files. It is very easy to
>   deploy, since there is no need to
>   install the server.